# O(n) algorithm that returns array indexes if condition is true

Tags: algorithm, search

I am trying to write an algorithm that takes a linear array, sorted from lowest to highest. It should return the positions of values if arr[i] - arr[j] = 160.

My problem is that the runtime should be O(n).

If I do it with a for loop that goes from highest to lowest array element, and for each element searches for appropriate array element with a binary search, the runtime is still O(n log2 n).

How can I reduce the complexity to O(n)?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us in more detail what you've tried and your thoughts on how your solution could be improved. This sounds very much like a homework problem, so people will probably be more eager to help you _along_ rather than write the program for you. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (now amit answered this quickly anyway, but for future questions, take a look at that link).

Comment: @dfri IMHO, the question is fine. He did show an attempted solution + analyzed its complexity, and came to the conclusion that it's not good enough. Only then, he asked how it can be improved. Seems good to me.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with two iterators, `i,j`, such that `i > j` always, and you increase `i` if `arr[i] - arr[j] > 160`, and increase `j` if `arr[i] - arr[j] < 160` (if it equals 160, you abort).

```
i = 1
j = 0
while (i < n):
   if (arr[i] - arr[j] == 160:
      // found it!
   else if (arr[i] - arr[j] < 160):
      i++
   else:
      j++
```

Comment: @pabrams [Homework questions are fine here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255477/572670). All questions require to show researh effort though, and this question did - by pointing at a solution, analyzing its complexity, and observing the problem with it. This question is fine IMHO.

Comment: I'm not saying any rules were broken here, just seems too easy for him that's all.  He'd have learned more by solving it himself IMO.

Comment: thank you amit,it is not homework question,I am just trying to understand concepts of writing fast algorithms,and I was overthinking instead of thinking of simple solution,as yours :D

Comment: @njok to be fair, this solution is not really *that* simple. It's called "two-pointers method" (or "technique"). Just because it requires little code, it doesn't mean that it's easy :)

Comment: The explanation wrongly describes the algorithm - increase i if the difference is >160, increase j if it's <160 -->  exactly opposite of what should be done (code is correct though). Also don't abort if the diff is exactly 160, just print/yield i&j, check following positions for repeating values (and print all combinations e.g. j,i+1 or j+1,i), and then increase both i and j to the new positions with larger values, and continue.